# Android :: Servlets, I'm trying to flush a stream to a servlet

Tags: android, servlets

i want to send an input stream from android to a servlet, but i dont think i can see the right way to communicate with the stream in android and the stream in the servlet, here is the sample for both:
android method:

```
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("name", "TheKeyword");
        httpConnection.connect();

        if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

and here is the servlet code:

```
inputStream = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        content = request.getParameter("name");


        if (content.equals("TheKeyword")) {
            ServerResponse = "32.024851:35.877249;31.9565783:35.945695;32.0833:36.1000;31.56:35.56;";
        } else {
            ServerResponse = "32.024851:35.877249;31.56:35.56;";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(ServerResponse);
    }

    response.getOutputStream().print(ServerResponse);
```

Please i need help.

Comment: What is the problem you have with this? Exception?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, i want to check the keyword because later on i will have more that a keyword and each one will return something, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an input stream you can use a multipart/request, like in a web form where you upload a file.